# If dinamicos en java

Tags: java

Supongamos que tengo un list d personas (NOMBRE,EDAD,FNACIMIENTO,CIUDAD,SEXO):

```
new Persona("Paco", 35, 05-05-1991,"Lisboa","H")
new Persona("Luis", 5, 05-05-1981,"Madrid","H")
new Persona("Pepe", 25, 05-05-1971,"Lisboa","H")
new Persona("Maria", 85, 05-05-1961,"Madrid","M")
new Persona("Marcos", 75, 05-05-1951,"Lisboa","H")
```

Y tengo un json:

```
var filter={ciudad:{check:true, value:'Madrid', operator:'='}, 
            fn:{check:true, value:'05-05-19970', operator:'>'}}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer los if dinámicos, suponiendo que el var filter puede venir N combianciones y yo solo necesito recuperar según lo que venga de filter?

Es decir, con este ejemplo querría todas las personas que fueran de 'madrid' y su fecha de nacimiento sea mayor a '05-05-19970'

No puedo poner por ejm:

```
if (persona.ciudad.equals('Madrid') {
     /// ya que esto no es dinámico no siempre compararé esto por: 
     1- persona.ciudad no siempre será un filtro, entonces tendria código que no usaré
}
```

NOTA: realmente no tengo objetos persona sino un json de personas

Comment: Que serían los "ifs dinamicos" ?

Comment: ¿If de qué o para qué? ¿Qué es lo que quieres buscar, comparar, filtrar?

Comment: acabo de actulizar la pregunta

Comment: if(persona.ciudad.equals(filter.ciudad.value) { .... }

Comment: no puedo poner persona.ciudad ya que a lo mejor ni siquiera en el var filter me viene ciudad y estoy poniendo codigo que no usare

Comment: if(filter.ciudad) { if(persona.ciudad.equals(filter.ciudad.value) { .... }  }

Comment: Estas mal, persona.ciudad siempre esta, aunque esta venga vacia, la variable existe

Comment: `Gson gson = new Gson();
   List<Empleado> empleados = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Empleado>>(){}.getType());
   for (Empleado empleado : empleados) {
    System.out.println(empleado.getId());
    System.out.println(empleado.getNombre());
    System.out.println(empleado.getPuesto());
    //Convierto el objeto empleado a cadena json
    System.out.println("json "+gson.toJson(empleado));
   }` En este caso mi clase empleado sería tu clase persona. y despues de eso puedes hacer condicones como la que te indicaron arriba `if(persona.ciudad.equals(filter.ciudad.value){}`

Comment: Para convertir el json en objetos java, puedes pegar el json en esta url http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/ y te genera las clases java que usarias con Gson como indico arriba.

Comment: Lo que pides no es algo que venga con el lenguaje; es algo que te tienes que programar (no, no hay una instrucción "dynamic if" que solo conocen los gurús de Java). Puedes curiosear con `streams` de Java 8 y con *Unified Expression Language* (UEL), pero a) ninguna de las dos es "dynamic if" pero te pueden ayudar a implementarlo y b) puede haber otras opciones, incluso mejores.

Comment: En realidad solo necesitas convertir el json en objetos java, recorrerlos como en una lista o array y adentro de ese ciclo poner ifs como el que comentaron arriba